Unable to connect to MongoDB database via Mongoose
I'm creating an app with the MERN stack, and I'm using Mongoose. Somehow it just refuses to connect to the database.
My code:
import {createRequire} from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
 
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 3000; 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = {my db uri}

mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected…')
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log("Connection is open...");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});


It keeps giving the following error

PS {project location}\src\server> node server
Server listening on port 3000
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors ({project location}\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:875:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C{project location}\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:826:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-01.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-02.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-00.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-f9m10v-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
Connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
    at EventTarget.<anonymous> ({project location}\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:276:34)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:807:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:742:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)
    at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:391:5)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> ({project location}\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:1011:92)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-01.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-02.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-xpydyff-shard-00-00.rn4suxq.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-f9m10v-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
  [cause]: MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET
      at connectionFailureError ({project location}\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> ({project location}\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
    [cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
      errno: -4077,
      code: 'ECONNRESET',
      syscall: 'read'
    }
  }
}

I've set my db to enable access from all IPs, and even tried using the default connection method provided by MongoDB without mongoose. I've looked through some other posts and deleted all the CORS-related lines. Still nothing works.
(trying to reach that word count trying to reach that word count trying to reach that word count)

It seems like your IP is not whitelisted in the MongoDB Atlas. Try adding your current IP address to IP access List Entry or add 0.0.0.0/0 as a permanent solution so that the database can be accessed from anywhere in the world. Note, use 0.0.0.0/0 only if the database is a development one, don't use it for production.

I've tried that already, but the problem persists

In that case try using MongoDB Compass to connect to the database first. If it works fine, then the issue is somewhere in your code.

The problem connecting to each node is obfuscated by the [ServerDescription] - can you increase depth or something to see that that actually contains?

Does your mongo URL include +SRV? If not, does it contain tls=true?  Atlas servers will summarily close connections that do not use TLS, without providing any kind of error message.

Thank you all, I figured it has something to do with my VPN. MongoDB seems to be blocking all requests from it which is weird cause I've already whitelisted every IP
